# Custom Filter with EF Core

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I found few answers here about this topic but they don't completely cover my question. 
My goal is to make entity has user as an owner. 
I define  an interface IMustHaveUser

```
public interface IMustHaveUser
{
    long UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I implement it in my entity Product

I register custom filter in EFCoreModule in preinitialize method

```
public override void PreInitialize() {
 //Register custom data filters
 Configuration.UnitOfWork.RegisterFilter("MustHaveUser", true);
 //other code here...
}
```

And finally setup my filter in DBContext
Define a property that checks that filter is enabled

```
protected virtual bool IsMustHaveUserFilterEnabled => CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider?.Current?.IsFilterEnabled("MustHaveUser") == true;
```

And override CreateFilterExpression method.

```
 protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()
    {
        var expression = base.CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>();

        if (typeof(IMustHaveUser).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
        {
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> userFilter = e => ((IMustHaveUser) e).UserId == AbpSession.UserId || (((IMustHaveUser) e).UserId == AbpSession.UserId) == IsMustHaveUserFilterEnabled;
            expression = expression == null ? userFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, userFilter);
        }


        return expression;
    }
```

Now, when I creating entity I have to manually setup UserID. 
Basically I wrote ProductManager in domain layer with method

```
void Create(Product product, UserIdentity user){
    product.UserId = user.UserId;
    //Other business rules and insert with repository

}
```

My question is about to setting up the current UserId. Is there other simplest (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I did it other way because this way make this code hard for integration tests. 
I don't know why documentation missing this moment, I had to read source from github to understand how existing filters work, for example  MustHaveTenant etc.
And I found there polymorphic method in AbpDbContext named ApplyAbpConceptsForAddedEntitywhich that allow me to implement it.

The final code in MyDbContext looks like:

```
    protected override void ApplyAbpConceptsForAddedEntity(EntityEntry entry, long? userId, EntityChangeReport changeReport)
    {
        CheckAndSetMustHaveUserIdProperty(entry.Entity, userId);
        base.ApplyAbpConceptsForAddedEntity(entry, userId, changeReport);
    }

    private void CheckAndSetMustHaveUserIdProperty(object entryEntity, long? userId)
    {
        if (userId == null)
            return;


        if (!(entryEntity is IMustHaveUser))
        {
            return;
        }

        var entity = entryEntity.As<IMustHaveUser>();


        entity.UserId = userId.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot about DI. Found the solution. Basically I've injected IAbpSession into Automapper profile and map UserId there.

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        private IAbpSession _abpSession;

        public AutoMapperProfile()        {

            _abpSession = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<IAbpSession>();



            CreateMap<LicenseInput, License>()
                .ForMember(x => x.UserId, options => options.MapFrom(src => _abpSession.UserId));


        }
    }
```

Comment: Great solution with automapper. Although that might not work for The .Host project for getters.

Comment: Have not tested it. I’m disabled multi-tenancy for my project, I don’t need it.  If you have better solution, please share.